# Customize Google Store Locator library to have markers not visible until you search

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My client wants a Map in his web store which is similar to that which can be accomplished with the Google Store Locator library. However, he wants the map not to display any marker until you search for a location, and just draw 3 stores. Then, when you search for other location, the map will be redrawn and only the 3 nearest markers will be printed.

I am playing around with the config files, and even with the JS files themselves, to no avail. It seems an easy task, but I cannot have the markers hidden. The list of stores I have been able to make it work using this code.

```
first_time = false;
...
...
if(!first_time){
  items_per_panel = 0;
  first_time = true;
}else{
    items_per_panel = 1;
} // if
```

However, I am completely stuck with the markers part. I suspect that I could customize the code which reads

```
 marker.setMap(this.getMap());
```

but don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I completed the code by using the item properties, item.getId(), and retrieving the list. I stored all the first elements by proximity, and then, in the method which draws the pins, I used this storing-array. Like this (my array is called stores_list):

```
  for (var i = 0, ii = Math.min(items_per_panel, stores.length); i < ii; i++) {
  // Get store data

  var storeLi = stores[i].getInfoPanelItem();

  stores_list.push(stores[i].getId()); // added line

 ....

 if(jQuery.inArray(store.getId(), stores_list) != -1 ) marker.setMap(this.getMap());  // added condition
```